# Finding the time it takes person A to catch up with person B

Tags: calculus

Person A and person B are walking in the same direction beside a railroad track, and A is far behind B. Both walk at constant speeds and A walks faster then B.
A long train travelling in the same direction will take $12$ seconds to pass A (from the front to the end) and will take $10$ seconds to travel pass B.
If the train takes $25$ minutes to travel from A to B how many minutes will it take A to catch up with B?
I started by setting up this equation:
$(vt-vA)/(vt-vB)=12/10$

Comment: Fix up your question man. Separate `A` and `B` properly, use a capital letter in every occurrence or non-capital letters in every occurrence, divide the paragraph into well separated lines, use LaTex wherever you have math symbols. In short, put some effort in your question if you're expecting others to put an effort answering it!

Comment: Tortoise and the hare--just to insert some philosophical vandalism :)

Comment: veterans here present please don't take things hard on me I am new here and really need your help

Comment: @Acafes: answerers are not motivated by how much you need an answer.  They are motivated by how easy the question is to answer.  And if they can't read it, they can't answer it.  As it stands post-edit there isn't a question.

Comment: Can you explain your equation? What are $vt$, $vA$ and $vB$?

Comment: $vt is the velocity of the train, $vA is thr velocity of person A anb $vB is the velocity of person B

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this kind of problem in years so I hope this is (more or less) correct. Let $v_A$, $v_B$ and $v_T$ be the velocities of $A$, $B$, and the train respectively. Let $l$ be the length of the train. Let $d$ be the distance between $A$ and $B$ and let $t$ be the time it takes for $A$ to catch $B$. Then we are trying to solve for $t$ in the equation,
\begin{align*}
v_At &=v_Bt + d 
\end{align*}
We are also given the following information,
\begin{align*}
12v_T &=12v_A+l \\
10v_T &=10v_B+l \\
1500v_T &=1500v_B+d 
\end{align*}

> My final solution is: 150 minutes.